# How can I specify accepted input objects for use by nswag?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, nswag

NSwag respects the attribute `ProducesResponseType` when building Swagger documents. E.g.

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyClass), 201)]
```

I want to specify input types. Is there an attribute such as `ConsumesRequestType` that I can use to specify multiple types? E.g.

```
[ConsumesRequestType(typeof(MyClass))]
```

If no, how can I make an attribute myself or achieve similar functionality? Thanks!